# Обработка исключений в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети

Есть обученная нейронка которая переводит текст с русского языка на английский.
При подачи в неё для перевода текста состоящего из английских букв,
 происходит ошибка - KeyError:

Как сделать так, что бы при подаче нейронке текста состоящего из английских букв
происходило исключение?
Если например пользователь случайно подал нейронке английское слово для перевода, то нужно, что бы происходил пропуск и появлялась возможность ввести слово заново.

Я пытаюсь решить так:

```py
while True:
    inputWord = input()
    translate(inputWord)
    engSimvols = ("[^a-zA-Z]")
    if engSimvols in inputWord:
      pass
```

Comment: Такая ошибка возникает при попытке получения из словаря значения по ключу, которого в словаре нет. В этом коде она не может возникнуть. Добавьте код функции translate.

Comment: И что, по-вашему, должно означать `engSimvols = ("[^a-zA-Z]")`?

Comment: по моему это должно означать набор символов при вводе вызывающих пропуск.

Comment: У вас с питоном разные мнения на этот счет. Приведите функцию, которая дает ошибку. Судя по коду, это функция `translate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import string
while True:
    try:
        input_word = input()
        if any(char in string.ascii_lowercase for char in input_word.lower().split()):
            raise KeyError()
        translate(input_word)
    except KeyError:
        print("Try again")
```

Comment: Создай класс своего Exception, отнаследовавашись от BaseException. И пропиши там нужное поведение. 
Извини за двусмысленнность.

Comment: Я не правильно задачу понял.
Ты хочешь, когда на вход приходит текст содержащий английские буквы возбуждалась ошибка KeyError?

Comment: хочу что бы не было ошибок, и текст можно было ввести заново, если пользователь случайно ввел в поле английские буквы.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! теперь всё работает как задумано!!! ..век не забуду!!)) да прибудет с тобой сила!!!))